# Why is non-standard analysis not fully or at all integrated in our current school systems (around the world)

Tags: analysis, soft-question, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

**Before you read my text down below.** I would want you to know that I am down below talking about education on all levels, but mostly on the levels that is below university level. But on university level, at least not in all parts of the world, non-standard analysis is not very widespread.

Non-standard analysis gives a more in-depth explanation and rigorous ground for understanding limits. While limits most often is taught implicitly and gives an implicit understanding - which makes it a hard subject to understand, for many new to the concepts of limits - non-standard analysis is a lot better method to use instead of limits, as it gives an explicit understanding. I would really believe that at least some areas of non-standard analysis should be given more place in regular education; the standard part function is a perfect example. Non-standard analysis are also a good and firm ground to have if you want to learn limits.

There exists an elementary book written on the subject, which unforunately did not make it all the way into our schools: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html.

I think non-standard analysis to be a good thing to educate students in, at an early level, if you want to give them understanding about certain parts of math. But traditional methods are closely held to.

Why are traditional methods so hard held to? Why not integrate non-standard analysis into current school systems?

Comment: From the accepted answer to @Kurow's link: *depending on one's tastes, non-standard analysis can be pretty entertaining to study, especially if one does not worry about the "theoretical" underpinnings. However, to be "rigorous" in use of non-standard analysis requires considerable effort, perhaps more than that required by other approaches. For example, the requisite model theory itself, while quite interesting if one finds such things interesting, is non-trivial.*

Comment: @DustanLevenstein

Comment: @Kurow I knew about this question you gave me before I wrote my own (as you probably can see by the tags I have used), but thank you even so.

Comment: Are you not convinced by the argument Dunstan quoted then?

Comment: The best answer I can offer you that is based on my own experience is that the math curriculum is already more than full (especially in the early level) and NSA relies on model theory which needs quite a bit of work if you want to do it right. Basically, one would have to put a lot of effort into teaching NSA, when the expected gain is not particularly impressive even under optimistic interpretations. I think you're already under the assumption that it is due to bias (?), which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @GEdgar This is not a duplicate as that question are too much based on biases (not all answers, though) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1620802/404146 may be a answer to this question, I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Kurow I think biases of non-standard analysis are too largely used and that's part of the reason to why I'm asking this question. Other reasons are that I want to know more about the current standing of non-standard analysis (the internet isn't precisely over-flowing on the subject). I'm only seventeen and have not gone to university or something like that, so I'm asking you who have. That is also why this question, from the beginning, was so shortly formulated. But that gave downvotes and no answers. Well, I don't know anymore.

Comment: @GEdgar Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1620802/404146 could be more thorough in his/her answer to depict the current situation even more.

Comment: @Kurow Good answer you had there, though.

Comment: @theHumbleOne Can you elaborate on your comment that "I think [Dustan's] comment to be a bias, a bias that don't depict the whole truth"? Personally I don't see how that statement is anything other than a correct statement of fact (and I say this as someone who *is* interested in model theory, and finds NSA really cool).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I may have misinterpreted his comment as I'm swede and not a foreign speaker of the English language. If you who know something about the subject doesn't think it to be a bias I withdraw my comment.

Comment: Nice edit. I'm sorry you got downvoted; this website can be a bit draconian sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a disclaimer: I'm of mixed opinions regarding nonstandard analysis in early curricula. Below I'm focusing mainly on the **objections** to NSA there, as that's what the question is asking about; my actual opinion is more balanced. (See the end of this answer.)

Second, a bit of context. There has been some research on the effectiveness of NSA in the curriculum; my understanding is that, while there has not been *much*, the results have been generally positive. In particular, the study I want to have in mind for what follows is the one summarized in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318657?seq=6#page_scan_tab_contents) by Kathleen Sullivan, which I will quote from a bit.

---

Here are some reasons I think NSA has not caught on, curriculum-wise:

- *Non-pervasiveness at the higher level*. Silly version first: if someone learns calculus via NSA, and then goes into mathematics, they will find themselves having to re-learn calculus to a certain extent, since NSA is *not* the language in which most analysis, at the research level, is currently conducted. OK, that's silly because it only applies to a tiny handful of students, and these are the students who are most equipped to learn multiple foundations; but we *also* see the same problem in higher-level math courses! Continuity in topology is now much more mysterious, since general topological spaces have no "hyperreal versions" (or rather, some do, but many don't); and classes building on analysis (complex analysis, differential geometry, etc.) would also need to be altered. So to do this properly, we wouldn't just need to change one class - large portions of the math curriculum would be affected. (Incidentally, note also that this would heavily affect transfer students, as well as students who have already seen some calculus via $\epsilon-\delta$ in high school.)

This issue is partly acknowledged by the Sullivan article:

> On the other hand, some uncertainty was voiced on the
>    question of how well students who want to study more analysis will be able to make the transition
>    from an experimental class to a traditional course. Conversations with students at the University of
>    Wisconsin, who had been in nonstandard calculus classes, suggest that the attitude of the instructor in
>    the standard class may be the crucial factor.

There is also the dual issue of *instructor unfamiliarity*, which interacts with the above objection in some obvious ways.

*Of course, there's the issue that NSA **is** useful and used at the research level! But it's still a very much minority tool. So my objection is still, I think, a serious one.*

- *Strange number system*. The real numbers form a nice number system - in particular, *every real is easily distinguishable from every other real*. Formally, given reals $r\not=s$, there is a first-order formula in the language of fields true of $r$ but not $s$, and vice-versa (look at a rational between $r$ and $s$ . . .). By contrast, any hyperreal field has lots of nontrivial automorphisms - that is, there will be lots of hyperreals which are indistinguishable from each other. This is a very weird property for a number system to have, and in my opinion is going to make the hyperreals a difficult concept for the students to grasp - in particular, the question "what is a hyperreal number?" is going to have a much less satisfying answer than the question "what is a real number?", and the student who asks for an *example* of an infinite/infinitesimal number may reasonably be very disappointed with the answer (I certainly was)! In particular, the more Platonistic students (and in my experience, a large number of students are what might be called "Platonist-by-default" - they've never seriously considered the question of mathematical existence, which to be fair is quite reasonable) will have good grounds for objecting to this approach.

Relatedly, there's the issue that many/most mathematicians - including me! - view the specific structure $\mathbb{R}$ as interesting and worthy of study, moreso than any specific hyperreal field, or indeed the general class of hyperreal fields. *Which is not to say that NSA doesn't shed light on $\mathbb{R}$* - obviously it does, that's the point - but rather that the $\epsilon-\delta$ framework is a beautiful construction, and interesting in its own right. Of course, the fact that I consider it beautiful is revealing of my own context as mathematician vs. student, so I'm not bringing this up as a main objection; but I think it's worth keeping in mind that this may be an objection the *instructors* have. And this may also be an issue for higher-level students; see below.

- *Difficulty of rigorous formulation*. Consider the honors section. It's easy to ground standard analysis in an "obviously consistent" theory - namely, develop the theory of the reals via Cauchy sequences, from basic set theory and the field axioms. Note my scare quotes around 'obviously consistent' - of course, I recognize that the consistency question for analysis is *much* more subtle than that! But my point is that an honors student seeing this development will with high probability be convinced that calculus is consistent. However, a strong calculus student may reasonably *not* be convinced of the consistency of NSA, specifically the question of why we believe we can postulate a hyperreal field! This is where the logical complexities of NSA become a problem - there *is no good answer* to this question which is accessible to the student at this time. Of course, this only applies to students who (a) are curious enough to challenge the consistency assumptions, and (b) are strong enough that they could follow the development of standard analysis; but there are lots of these students, so it would be odd to ignore them.

Alright, let's get a rebuttal. Note that all the objections above were focused on the higher-level students, to varying extents. This is because as long as the students do not continue on to higher math classes, and as long as questions about mathematical reality, consistency, and the like are not brought up, NSA seems to have a strong advantage. Again, from the Sullivan article:

> The [NSA] group was also given the edge regarding
>    the ease with which they were able to learn the basic concepts. One instructor commented that, "When
>    my most recent class were presented with the epsilon-delta definition of limit, they were outraged by its
>    obscurity compared to what they had learned."

---

Let me finish by putting some "skin in the game" and stating my own opinion for all to see:

I think NSA is undoubtedly the better framework for the student who intends to learn calculus, and not proceed further in mathematics. *And this is a large number of students, and a reasonable position to hold on their part*. I think the situation is much more mixed - though by no means necessarily fully, or even mostly, negative! - with regard to students who intend to continue on to higher-level math classes, and potentially a serious detriment to those who intend to go into research mathematics (also, to be fair, potentially a serious boon - my point is that I'm worried, not that I'm certain of negative outcomes). I also think that it would meet with resistance on the part of many/most instructors; while this isn't an "ideal" problem, it's a reality that has to be acknowledged. And I am doubtful that it would vanish over time, given the difference in roles of standard analysis vs. nonstandard analysis in research mathematics (although it probably would diminish).

Ultimately, I want more data. For one thing, the study analyzed in the Sullivan article was quite small; for another, it didn't have anything to say about the students' future math classes. *I could be convinced that NSA is the superior method*, but currently I am not.

*And of course the above is not in any way meant to obviate my  many and strong objections to all sorts of things surrounding calculus in the curriculum; but that's a very different issue, so I'll stop here.*

Comment: One quibble: in my experience most students who are stopping after calculus are taking cookbook courses and don’t really get any theoretical treatment of limits anyway, so the question is moot.

Comment: I was responding to ‘I think NSA is undoubtedly ...’. I really don’t think that this is true for the vast majority of the students in question, not because it’s a worse approach for them, but because they aren’t going to need any approach beyond handwaving. (For the most part I agree with what you’ve written; that’s my upvote.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, whoops - I misinterpreted your comment. My bad. The reason for my strong preference is not predicated on them *needing* it - rather, I think a vastly greater fraction will get something out of it, than via the standard approach. By "something," I don't mean technical tools - I mean an appreciation for the beauty of mathematics. In the same way that I was required to take classes in philosophy, literature, music, etc. (and loved it!), I think this is something that I would like even non-mathy students to get. (cont'd)

Comment: Now, actually, I would prefer the "math for poets" class to not be calculus in *any* form! I think there are many better things to do for that audience (which, btw, is an audience I greatly respect! nothing in the above should be taken as denigration). But, *if* we're committing to that class being a calculus class, then NSA is the way I would want it done.

Comment: I think that I’d agree, except that I can’t imagine basing one on calculus; I’d go so far as to call that blatant idiocy! Being almost the only member of our department who actually enjoyed it, I taught many, many liberal arts math classes over the years, some of my own devising, and calculus is just about the *last* thing that I’d consider for subject matter. Some elementary combinatorial game theory worked pretty well, and I even had some success with formations of marching ants (countable ordinals), to name a couple that I especially liked.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My understanding (though I could easily be wrong) is that lots of places (very unfortunately!) use calculus, or something calculus-y, as a math-for-poets-style class. For instance, if I recall correctly, UChicago (where I did my undergrad) had a remedial math class, and a sorta-kinda math-for-poets class based on a bit of number theory and (IIRC) low-level quasi-linear-algebra; but most poets I knew wound up taking the 130s sequence, which was the lowest-level of the calc sequences. And, if I recall correctly, not one poet I talked to who did this enjoyed it. So I think we agree?

Comment: It certainly sounds like it. In the other direction, in one of my more idiosyncratic liberal arts math classes I had an English major who was part of the staff of a small local literary magazine. At her graduation a year or two later she told me that she’d enjoyed the course and had been surprised to find that some of it even resonated with her interests.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's awesome, and exactly the thing I'd hope for. I've not yet had the opportunity to teach a MFP class, but I'm looking forward to it; I think combinatorial game theory looks right now like the most appealing topic. (I gave a talk to a bunch of not-particularly-mathy fifth graders a couple years ago, on Hackenbush; we talked about when two games are the same, etc. They seemed to enjoy it a lot, and I heard that Hackenbush become popular, at least for a couple weeks.)